What's the history of defining the amplitude of a complex number as its argument(phase)?
I see some confusing definitions saying the amplitude of a complex number is the argument or phase of the complex number, as in the following examples.

What is the amplitude of a complex number?

Here, r is the modulus and θ is the amplitude or argument of a complex number.


Amplitude or Argument of a Complex Number

In this article, we will learn about the complex numbers, definition of argument of complex numbers, ...


What is the amplitude of a complex number?

Thus, for any unique value of θ that lies in the interval −π < θ ≤ π ... is known as the amplitude of z and it is denoted by Amp(z).



What's the history of these definitions? I even found some naive questions using those here, which means some teachers or textbooks are still using them.

My copy of Complex Analysis, 3rd edition (1979), by Lars Ahlfors, defines the "argument or amplitude" of a complex number on page 13. I'm fairly sure I've seen it elsewhere in print long ago. I believe amplitude is a more old-fashioned synonym of argument, but being old-fashioned doesn't make it "wrong". I do notice that it seems to be particularly popular among people who trained in India; all three of your links appear to me to be Indian.

Might be suitable for HSM SE.

^ I second that.

My wild guess would be that the use of "amplitude" in this context arose out of Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ and its connection with the amplitude of a wave, in physics.

One context which retains "amplitude as angle" is the Jacobi amplitude function, with the use of the word "amplitude" dating back to Legendre's 1786 work on the subject.

Amplitude is just another way, though bit more old-fashioned, of saying argument. There is nothing wrong with it.
